# How a world without evil need to be like? (A different set of laws of physics?)

Tags: internal-consistency

Evil here is defined as one self-aware entity intentionally harming a self-aware entity. Is it possible to have a world consisting of at least two self-aware entities be without evil (in a world with only one self-aware entity evil is equivalent to self-harm)?

Is it possible to have a different set of laws of physics so that helping other entities will not harm the helper? I believe the laws of physics inherently encourage evil by making every entity that give other entities energy lose energy.

For example if we have a game universe where every player that gives another player one coin gains two from the system and see how this is going to work out.

Comment: What do you consider to be self-aware? Rocks and trees are out (as far as we can tell) and humans are in (because we define everything around ourselves), but what about dogs, dolphins, and cicadas?

Comment: Doggies, kittens, dolphins and cicadas are in.

Comment: "one self-aware entity harming another" - does it need to be intentional harm?  What about a case where the mere existence of entity B causes entity A harm, either through a physical process or pure narcissism?

Comment: It has to be intentional, either in the sense of directly causing harm, or in the sense of knowing that some other entity is coming to harm but do nothing about it when the entity reasonably should do so.

Well for example we can argue whether the mere existence of mice in some area around me for example cause me harm, or is my dislike of mice that is the real reason I get troubled.

Comment: I'd like to point out that a universe with this definition of evil could not support evolution, which is predicated on competition. It would have to be a construct, and an ecosystem within this universe would have no natural means of self-induced change.

Comment: I do not believe that any form of evolution is not supported without this definition of evil, but certainly not the form of evolution based on a zero-sum game. It has to make sure that winners of evolution are not those who are the most destructive to other entities.

There will still be natural means of self-induced change, because the desire to improve oneself and makes one's lives better still exist. (But by improve, I do not mean improve the ability, desire and ruthlessness to harm other entities. There should be a way to improve oneself without harming others.)

Comment: What especially should be abolished is the conservation of mass and energy. This is one of the key roots of the system of evil.

Comment: I see a lot of opportunities regarding adjusting the apparent distance between self-aware entities.  Is it evil for a self-aware entity to try to hurt another self-aware and fail, or is it only evil when they succeed at hurting the other?  Also, are you looking for *definitely* no evil, or for evil to be reduced asymptotically as time progresses (i.e. "evil always loses")?

Comment: Also, is it valid to have evil in the universe, but for it to be invisible to all non-evil self-aware entities?  (An agent of entropy itself could be considered evil, if it were to be deemed self-aware)

Comment: @CortAmmon Evil only exists when intentional harming of other self-aware entities is successful. The best thing I look for is the absolute nonexistence of evil. The second best thing is evil reduces over time. The third best thing if the things before is impossible is whether the universe can be blind to evil as opposed to encourage and even enforce it. (The current universe encourage, if not outright enforce and press evil onto entities) The fourth best is at least there exists some self-aware entity that can refuse evil without being destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Communal Resources

I'm extrapolating a bit here, but it seems like the direction you are going with this is marginally resource based, specifically about giving and taking energy. e solution to this would be to make all entities draw from a common resources. Thus, stealing energy from one entity reduces your own pool, while helping another entity create more energy, or use it more efficiently, would help you as well.

### Assumptions

- **Entities are rational actors.** This means do what's in their own best interest. They wouldn't purposefully reduce their own resources
  without reason, wouldn't be willing to hurt themselves just to hurt
  others, etc.
- **There is no non-communal storage.** At first glance, the idea sounds bad, because you  every entity just taking as much resource as
  they can, thus selfishly hurting everyone else. The key idea though,
  that there would be nowhere put it, no form to store energy in a
  personal way. Thus, taking more than you need would simply become
  wasting your own resources, and not a rational move.
- **Harm wastes resources.** The final piece needed here, is that harming another entity would also harm the communal pool of energy.
  So by weakening another entity, would not be reducing competition for
  the resource pool, but be reducing capacity instead.

### Visualization

One way to picture this would be as a usable life-force, akin to Star Wars. Each person contributes to part of a galactic pool of energy, and the healthier they are the more energy they contribute. Thus, hurting anyone reduces the energy available to everyone, and is not a smart move.

Comment: Communism works exactly in this way. But it seems that it does not work. First of all people that share everything do not necessarily want to contribute much to the community (free ride problem). Also even if people have almost the same amount of money they still struggle for power and other things and this struggle can still be deadly.

Comment: @YingZhou That's why those assumptions are important. Communism fails all 3. People can steal and hide food for personal gain, killing your neighbor sometimes just means more food for you, not less, and calling Humans rational actors is kind of a stretch

Comment: In a sufficiently large community personal contribution to the community does not influence what one gains from the community a lot. Hence it may be desirable for an actor to not contribute to the community a lot. Unless this is easy to detect and prevent it is going to be a problem.

Comment: @YingZhou I mean, obviously in this world it's unfeasible, but for actual rational actors, any gain is by definition worth it and will be pursued

Answer (score 2):

**Changing physics won't help.**

Life is a gas, it expands to fill its container.

If the universe gives free energy to those give it, then life will expand until physical space is the limiting factor. The evolutionary pressure would be to be able to give away as much energy as possible in the smallest amount of space.

Evil isn't a thing, it's one end of a spectrum. If you squish the spectrum up to be the worst things would be what we consider "ok" and the best are "sooo excellent" then "ok" is the new evil. Please look up the concept of [FWP](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=First%20World%20Problems) to see this in action.

Under the conditions given, to have two self-aware entities in a universe without them causing harm to the other put them on opposite sides of the universe. In this way they will never interact and will never be able to harm one another.

Comment: If self-aware entities can never have any influence on each other then of course evil by definition can not exist. But other than that, is this possible, may I ask?

Comment: @YingZhou Only if the definition of evil from this world is used. However, that seems unlikely and a new definition of evil would be used in a different universe. Evil is, "not good" in the same way that good is "not evil", if you have one, you have the other.

Comment: I believe that the definition of "evil" should be static and rational, like formal logic. I know humans are evil, conformist (again you can not conform to others without being evil) and have a lot of other undesirable characteristics. Can this be changed?

Comment: @YingZhou Please provide the formal logic definition of evil. It shouldn't depend on viewpoint, bias, or religious background. Don't just say it's known, I want the formula. Given that, along with evidence of its existence in our universe, I can answer your question on if and how it can be changed.

Comment: OK. For any self-aware entities $A$ and $B$ in the universe $U$, $A$ intentionally harms $B$ is denoted as $H(A,B)$. $A$ being evil to $B$ is denoted as $E_0(A,B)$, $A$ being evil is denoted as $E(A)$.

$H(A,B)$ is equivalent to $E_0(A,B)$.
$E(A)$ is defined as $\exists B\in U$ such that $H(A,B)$

Comment: You need to further define the function H.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27064/discussion-between-ying-zhou-and-samuel).